# Function Doesn't Return a value in Dart Language

Tags: api, asynchronous, dart, linear-search

I am trying to connect my app to an API and search using the API. If the search is successful and found the name, it will return `Success` and if not, will return `Failed`, but it doesn't return anything.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

main() {
 getData();
}


String linearSearch(List<dynamic> list, String x) {
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    if(x == list[i]["name"]){
      return 'Success';
    }
  }
  return 'Failed';
}

void getData() async {
  List data;
  var response = await    
  http.get("http://localhost:3000/data");
  data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  linearSearch(data, 'karim');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function returns `String` value without any additions. You just need to assign result of your function to `String` variable and do something with it, if needed.
Or you just could print result of the function

```
void getData() async {
  List data;
  var response = await    
  http.get("http://localhost:3000/data");
  data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(linearSearch(data, 'karim'));
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Solved by editing my linearSearch function

```
linearSearch(List<dynamic> list, String x) {
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
if(x == list[i]["name"]){
  return print('Success');
}
}
return print('Failed');
}
```

Comment: You should not write `return print(...);`. The return type of `print` is `void`, and you should never use the result of a `void` expression for anything. Instead use: `print("Success"); return;` to print and then return.